# TryEnterReadLock vs EnterReadLock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am using an implementation of a `ThreadSafeQueue` and an implementation of a `ThreadSafeDictionary` downloaded from somewhere and they are using two different ways to lock the code, one does:

```
        readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim LockQ = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        public void Enqueue(T item)
        {
            LockQ.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                m_Queue.Enqueue(item);
            }

            finally
            {
                LockQ.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
```

Which I believe is quite classic. The other one is:

```
public static class Locks
    {
        public static ReaderWriterLockSlim GetLockInstance()
        {
            return GetLockInstance(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
        }

        public static ReaderWriterLockSlim GetLockInstance(LockRecursionPolicy recursionPolicy)
        {
            return new ReaderWriterLockSlim(recursionPolicy);
        }

        public static void GetReadLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            var lockAcquired = false;
            while (!lockAcquired)
                lockAcquired = locks.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(1);
        }

        public static void GetReadOnlyLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            var lockAcquired = false;
            while (!lockAcquired)
                lockAcquired = locks.TryEnterReadLock(1);
        }

        public static void GetWriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            var lockAcquired = false;
            while (!lockAcquired)
                lockAcquired = locks.TryEnterWriteLock(1);
        }

        public static void ReleaseLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            ReleaseWriteLock(locks);
            ReleaseReadLock(locks);
            ReleaseReadOnlyLock(locks);
        }

        public static void ReleaseReadLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            if (locks.IsUpgradeableReadLockHeld)
                locks.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }

        public static void ReleaseReadOnlyLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            if (locks.IsReadLockHeld)
                locks.ExitReadLock();
        }

        public static void ReleaseWriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            if (locks.IsWriteLockHeld)
                locks.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

public abstract class BaseLock : IDisposable
    {
        protected ReaderWriterLockSlim _Locks;

        public BaseLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
        {
            _Locks = locks;
        }

        public abstract void Dispose();
    }

 public class WriteLock : BaseLock
    {
        public WriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim locks)
            : base(locks)
        {
            Locks.GetWriteLock(_Locks);
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            Locks.ReleaseWriteLock(_Locks);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        using (new WriteLock(dictionaryLock))
        {
            dict.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Which seems an overkill to me, but there must be some reason why this has been done?

I would like to know if the simplest version is good enough or if I should use the safe version and in which situations.

is `TryEnterReadLock` a way to escape deadlocks? If this is true, does it mean that `EnterReadLock` will anyway eventually work as long as there aren't deadlocks? I just want to understand if it makes sense to be safe in a normal scenario

Comment: The 2nd snippet is just very ugly code that completely misunderstands how RWL works.  It probably works okay, but it is mostly by accident.  Just don't assume whomever wrote that code knew what he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: The simple version is adequate but acquires a more restrictive lock every time. The longer version has lot of bloat.

**Long Answer**:
Some of the code from Snippet #2 is just there since it is a separate class. For example, `ReleaseReadOnlyLock` needs to check before releasing since it can't trust the caller to have already acquired the read lock. Now if you use the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` object directly, the onus is already on you to acquire the read lock before calling release.

Some places it simple provides convenience. For example, `ReleaseLock` simple provides a convenient interface to release all types of locks.

And in some other places, it is redundant. For example: `GetReadOnlyLock`, typically we use a `TryEnterReadLock` if we plan to do something when it fails. If we only want to keep waiting for it we can just call `EnterReadLock` which does exactly that.

Also, the `WriteLock` class provides a [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) syntax

In the simpler version of the code, I don't see any utilization of `read locks`. If that is the case, you just need the `lock(someLockObj)` statement, instead of a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

You can build some custom logic to prevent deadlocks based on the return value of `TryEnterReadLock`, but that would need a well founded strategy and corresponding code in your code snippet (not at the callers)

Comment: it's TryEnterReadLock a way to escape deadlocks? If this is true, does it mean that EnterReadLock will anyway eventually work as long as there aren't deadlocks? I just want to understand if it makes sense to be safe in a normal scenario.

Comment: @sebas As you notice the `while` loop will become an infinite loop if `TryEnterReadLock` never succeeds. From that perspective, it is no better in dealing with a deadlock than its `EnterReadLock` variant. Now, can you build some deadlock handling strategy on top of the results from `TryEnterReadLock`? Sure, but the current code does nothing like that

Comment: thanks so I just go with the simpler version basically